# mount.ntfs process taking up CPU

Tags: 12.04, mount, wubi, ntfs, process

Recently in Ubuntu Desktop 12.04, I've found (in the top command) that the process mount.ntfs has been constantly running, and taking up about 15% of my CPU.

I checked to make sure that I hadn't mounted either the C:/ drive that ubuntu is installed on (with WUBI) or any of the other ntfs partitions, but none were mounted.

This is a recently occurring problem, what is the process and is it safe to kill it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't kill it. The host `NTFS` partition is mounted as `/host`.

Running `df` will show you, for example, in this case the host partition is `/dev/sda3`

```
bcbc@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       15G  7.3G  7.0G  51% /
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           751M  920K  750M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  416K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda3       295G  113G  183G  39% /host
bcbc@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Is there any way to minimize the CPU use, since I can't really unmount it without unmounting the ubuntu system files?

Comment: @Moboman you could do a normal dual boot. Wubi is mainly for trying out for Ubuntu and it's being phased out. So... that's what I'd suggest.